# Google Webmaster Tool API in c#

Tags: c#, .net, api, webservice-client, google-search-console

I want to use Google Webmaster Tool API in c# application. I have gone through different documents that are available on https://developers.google.com. Unfortunately I did not get any working example of using Google WT API using .Net . I have also seen the “Client Libraries” (“https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/client-libraries”) for this.

Can anybody provide me any working example of how to use Google Webmaster Tool API in c# ?

I have account on Google WT, and want to download .CSV reports for “CrawlErrors”, “InternalLinks”,” TopSearchQueries” etc.

Thanks

Comment: According to protocol summary you can do just a few things with protocol:
    View a list of sites in your account
    Add and remove sites from your account
    Verify site ownership
    Modify site settings
    Retrieve a list of the keywords Google has found on your site
    Submit and delete Sitemaps
    Manage messages sent to your account by Google via the Message Center in Webmaster Tools
    Retrieve a list of issues Google discovered while crawling your site.
so I guess it is not the way to get all reports  OR you want to get reports from ANALYTICS instead of webmaster tools

Answer (score 6):

Here you can find the **official C# library source code for [Webmaster Tools Data API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/reference)**:
http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/src/webmastertools/

And here you can find **examples of usage** in the form of unit tests:
http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/src/unittests/webmastertools/

More specifically, examples of authentication, QuerySites, QuerySitemaps, QueryKeywords, etc.:
http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/src/unittests/webmastertools/WebmasterToolsServiceTest.cs

Note also there are some bug reports, your mileage may vary:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/gh7vCzYfm6A

If you're still getting `403 Forbidden`, the reason behind this might be the **2-Step Verification** installed on your Google account. If that's the case, try generating a dedicated password in the [Application-specific passwords](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMabEyrtPRg&t=2m13s) section of your Google account, and use it with `GDataCredentials(this.userName, this.passWord)`.

Alternatively, you may try adding sub-accounts at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/user-admin and use of one of them. The **2-Step Verification** concern may apply to those accounts, too.

Comment: I ended up getting the login to work by creating an application specific password. AFAIK GWT have shut down a lot of the official API functionality. I managed to write my own code based on a php library. I'll look into the code you referenced for more ideas. Cheers.

Comment: most of the links are dead